# UDP connection between C server and Java client

Tags: java, c++, c, udp, client-server

I have another question :) I have a simple UDP server in C that reads some bytes applies some decode to those bytes and when it has a STRING of the form ###@####@###@### he sends it throug UDP to another server in C. Here is the code for my C server that is called preprocesamiento.c Im posting the whole thing cos is easyer but maybe this has nothing to do with my problem.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#define MAXBUF 512
#define SENDING 0x52
#define RESIVING 0xB4
#define TYPE 0xA3F0

int createSocket();
char *unbase64(unsigned char *input, int length);
/* This function recives bytes(ASCII numbers) and returns the char */
void cambiarAChars(char* bytes, char* result)

  {

unsigned int ch;

    char a[4];
    char buff[50];
    strcpy(result,"");
    int i=0;
    while(i<strlen(bytes))
    {
      if(bytes[i]=='1')
       {

    a[0]=bytes[i];
    a[1]=bytes[i+1];
    a[2]=bytes[i+2];
    a[3]='\0';
    i=i+3;
   }
else

{
    a[0]=bytes[i];
    a[1]=bytes[i+1];
    a[2]='\0';
    i=i+2;
}
ch = atoi(a);
sprintf(buff,"%c",ch);
strcat(result,buff);
    }
 }
 /*this is the message that is going to be sent to the other server*/
char msg[MAXBUF];
 /*this is the bytes recived*/
char bytes[MAXBUF];
void loadConfig(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer,struct sockaddr_in *thisServer,unsigned char *file);

 int sendDataToServerXX(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer, int udpSocket);
 int *useStdrr;
 int *maxRequests;
 int returnStatus;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
 if (argc < 2)
     {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file.config adress>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(1);

     }
useStdrr=malloc(sizeof(int));
maxRequests=malloc(sizeof(int));
    struct sockaddr_in  udpServer,thisServer,udpClient;
    loadConfig(&udpServer,&thisServer, argv[1]);
    int thisServerSocket = createSocket();
    int udpSocket=createSocket();
int addrlen;


printf("Listening on.. %d \n",thisServer.sin_port);



thisServer.sin_family = AF_INET;

returnStatus = bind(thisServerSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&thisServer, sizeof(thisServer));



if (returnStatus == 0) {



    fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");



 } 

 else {



    fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address \n" );





    close(thisServerSocket);

    exit(1);

  }



/*En este while infinito estamos esperando los datos de las tramas*/

while (1)
   {





    addrlen = sizeof(udpClient);

    /* How to resive a struct? */

    returnStatus = recvfrom(thisServerSocket,(char*)&bytes, sizeof(bytes), 0, 

                            (struct sockaddr*)&udpClient, &addrlen);



        if (returnStatus == -1) {



                fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive message!\n");





        } 





        else {



        printf("Lo que llego: %s \n",bytes);

        /*Primero quitamos el 0 y 1 y guardamos el nuevo arreglo en p*/



        bytes[strlen(bytes)-1]='\0';



        char  p[strlen(bytes)];

        int i=0;

        while(bytes[i+1]!='\0'){



            p[i]=bytes[i+1];

            i++;

        }





        /*esto simula la cambiada a base10 de base64*/

        char *result=malloc(512);

        char *p2=malloc(sizeof(p)+1);

        strcpy(p2,p);

        cambiarAChars(p2,result);



        strcat(result,"\n\0");

        printf("TAMANO: %d \n",strlen(result));

        char *output = unbase64(result, strlen(result));

        printf("Unbase64: %s\n", output);



        msg[0]='%';

        strcat(msg,output);
        int f=strlen(msg);
        msg[f]='%';
        msg[f+1]='\0';

        printf("Voy a mandar: %s \n",msg);

        sendDataToServerXX(&udpServer,udpSocket);

        free(output);




        }







}



close(thisServerSocket);

    close(udpSocket);

 }



 int createSocket()

 {

 /* create a socket */

int Socket;

  Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);



  if (Socket == -1)

  {

    if(*useStdrr)

        {

    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");

    }

    exit(1);

  }

  else {

    printf("Socket created.\n");

   }

return Socket;

 }



 void loadConfig(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer,struct sockaddr_in *thisServer, unsigned char *file)

{

 char line[256];

 int linenum=0;

  FILE* f = fopen(file, "r");

while(fgets(line, 256, f) != NULL)

{

    char atribute[256], value[256];



    linenum++;

    if(line[0] == '#'||line[0] == ' ') {

    continue;

    }

    else{

    if(sscanf(line, "%s %s", atribute, value) != 2)

    {

            fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error, line %d\n", linenum);

            continue;

    }



    if(!strcmp(atribute,"server_address" ))

    {

        if(!strcmp(value,""))

        {

        udpServer->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        }

        else{

        udpServer->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(value);

        }

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"server_port"))

    {

        udpServer->sin_port = htons(atoi(value));

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"print_message_details"))

    {

        if(!strcmp(value,"ON"))

        {

            *useStdrr=1;

        }

        else

        {

            *useStdrr=0;

        }

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"request_count"))

    {

        *maxRequests=5;

    }



    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"valor_que_viene_del_cohete_simulado"))

    {







    }



    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"this_server_address"))

    {

        if(!strcmp(value,""))

        {

            thisServer->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        }

        else{

            thisServer->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(value);

        }

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"this_server_port"))

    {

        thisServer->sin_port = htons(atoi(value));



    }

}



}

 }



  int sendDataToServerXX(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer, int udpSocket)

  {
   udpServer->sin_family = AF_INET;

int in=0;

int boolv=0;



while(in<*maxRequests)

{

    in++;



    returnStatus = sendto(udpSocket,(char*) &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, 

                      (struct sockaddr*)udpServer, sizeof(*udpServer));



    if (returnStatus == -1) {

        if(*useStdrr)

        {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not send message!\n");



        }

    }

    else {





        printf("Datos enviados al servidor xx.\n");

            memset(msg, 0, strlen(msg));

        in=*maxRequests;

        boolv=1;



  }

}

if(!boolv)

{

    if(*useStdrr)

    {

    fprintf(stderr, "fixed number of requests finished.. no reply.\n");

    }

}

 return 0;
 }


 char *unbase64(unsigned char *input, int length)

 {

  BIO *b64, *bmem;
  char *buffer = (char *)malloc(length);

  memset(buffer, 0, length);



  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());

  BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

   bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(input, length);

   bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

   BIO_read(bmem, buffer, length);
   BIO_free_all(bmem);



 return buffer;

 }
```

Ok so i made a simulator that sends data to this server... basically a UDP client that sends bytes as i want them. And the connection and the whole thing works very nice :). Now im trying to connect to the real tester, which is a java jar that sends data as my server wants it through UDP. The only problem is that i dont have the java source code, because its not mine... But the program seems to run smoothly (the java jar) But when i check my server no connections where recived. And yeah im waiting in the right port and both programs the C and Java are running in the same machine (UBUNTU).

I post my client simulator made in C that works very nice with this server.

Sorry its a bit long cos i load from a config file:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
  #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <string.h>
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define SENDING 0x52
#define RESIVING 0xB4
 #define TYPE 0xA3F0

int createSocket();


char msg[MAXBUF];





 void loadConfig(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer, char *file);

  int *useStdrr;

  int *maxRequests;

  int *timeOut;



  int main(int argc, char* argv[])

 {

   int returnStatus;

   int addrlen;

   struct sockaddr_in udpClient, udpServer;

   char buf[MAXBUF]; 

useStdrr=malloc(sizeof(int));

maxRequests=malloc(sizeof(int));

timeOut=malloc(sizeof(int));

/*ms.timezone="AES";*/



   if (argc < 2)

   {    

       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file.config adress>\n", argv[0]);


    exit(1);

  }



int udpSocket=createSocket();

   udpServer.sin_family = AF_INET;


loadConfig(&udpServer, argv[1]);



/*how to send a struct here?*/

int in=0;

int boolv=0;

printf("Request number %i\n",*maxRequests);

while(in<*maxRequests)

{

    in++;

    printf("Request number %i\n",in);





    printf("Adresss::: %d\n",udpServer.sin_addr.s_addr);

    printf("PORT:::: %i\n",udpServer.sin_port);



    returnStatus = sendto(udpSocket,(char*) &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, 

                      (struct sockaddr*)&udpServer, sizeof(udpServer));



    if (returnStatus == -1) {

        if(*useStdrr)

        {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not send message!\n");



        }

    }

    else {



    printf("Message sent.\n");



    /* message sent: look for confirmation */

/*

    addrlen = sizeof(udpServer);



    returnStatus = recvfrom(udpSocket, (char*) &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, 

                            (struct sockaddr*)&udpServer, &addrlen);



    if (returnStatus == -1) {

        if(*useStdrr)

        {

        fprintf(stderr, "Did not receive confirmation!\n");

        }

    }





    else {



        printf("Second: %s\n", msg);





        */

        in=*maxRequests;

        boolv=1;

        /*







    }*/



  }

}

if(!boolv)

{

    if(*useStdrr)

    {

    fprintf(stderr, "fixed number of requests finished.. no reply.\n");

    }

}





 close(udpSocket);

 return 0;



 }



 int createSocket()

 {

 /* create a socket */

int Socket;

 Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);



 if (Socket == -1)

 {

    if(*useStdrr)

        {

    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");

    }

    exit(1);

 }

 else {

    printf("Socket created.\n");

 }

return Socket;

 }



  void loadConfig(struct sockaddr_in *udpServer, char *file)

  {

   char line[256];

    int linenum=0;




    FILE* f = fopen(file, "r");

while(fgets(line, 256, f) != NULL)

{

    char atribute[256], value[256];



    linenum++;

    if(line[0] == '#'||line[0] == ' ') {

    continue;

    }

    else{

    if(sscanf(line, "%s %s", atribute, value) != 2)

    {

            fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error, line %d\n", linenum);

            continue;

    }

    printf("Atribute: %s\n",atribute);

    printf("Value: %s\n",value);

    if(!strcmp(atribute,"server_address" ))

    {

        if(!strcmp(value,""))

        {

        udpServer->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        }

        else{

        udpServer->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(value);

        }

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"server_port"))

    {

        udpServer->sin_port = htons(atoi(value));

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"print_message_details"))

    {

        if(!strcmp(value,"ON"))

        {

            *useStdrr=1;

        }

        else

        {

            *useStdrr=0;

        }

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"request_count"))

    {

        *maxRequests=atoi(value);

    }

    else if(!strcmp(atribute,"request_*timeOut"))

    {

        *timeOut=atoi(value);

    }


}



}

 }
```

Now the real QUESTION: Do i have to do something different to connect froma java client to a C from the C server than what i do to connect to another C client? If the answer is no then the problem is in the java project? they tell me its working fine but I think they have tested it with a JAVA server.. Is there any diference?  If the problem is in the java project what should i tell them to change for it to work with my C server?

Many thx !!!

Alejandro Casas

Comment: If the Java server is sending out UDP via the network stack, then you should be able to use UDP client written in any language to receive that data.  Have you used a tool like wireshark to verify the packets are coming out of the Java server?

Comment: @Alejandro, if you are not going to take the time to clean up your source, then its hard to expect other users to take their valuable time to help you for free...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a UDP connection. In UDP, a program just tosses packets at a given port at a given IP. If there is nothing listening at that IP/port, or the receiving program decides to ignore the UDP packets, it gets dropped. If you want an actual connection, you would use TCP.

In addition, some ISP block some types of UDP packets by default

In Java, a TCP socket is called a Socket and a UDP socket is called a DatagramSocket. Make sure you are sending from a DatagramSocket on your Java client.

I haven't done socket programming in C though.

Finally, it would help if you posted some of your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example on how to start developing a Java client/server.
Notice it comes from "Computer Networking: A Top Down Approach", by Kurose and Ross
The book has both UDP/TCP examples in **JAVA**, which are great and I recommend you.

The UDP server/client: 
http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

The TCP server/client: 
http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/