# Is it possible for two process in different languages to communicate by using UDP

Tags: android, c, linux, udp, ipc

I need to implement UDP for two process, but both are wrote in different languages, and different platforms.

Is it possible for two process in different languages to communicate by using UDP?

Comment: yes, for UDP is not relevant what language the code is written

Comment: Yes, it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673072/udp-connection-between-c-server-and-java-client

Comment: Therefore are protocols!

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately this question is off-topic as it's way too broad. The implementation language is completely independent of the transport protocol as it should be

Comment: Yes, standard protocols are specifically made for this goal.

Comment: @EdChum If the implementation language is independent of the transport protocol, how is it too broad? And how is it too broad when the answer is either yes or no?

Comment: @EJP fair point, yes it's a straight yes/no question. I interpreted this as some kind of larger request but it is still a poor question nonetheless

Comment: @EdChum It's not adequate to characterize this as a poor question without providing an actual reason. The only reason you have advanced doesn't apply, as you have now agreed.

Comment: If the processes are on the same machine *and* its Unix or Linux, then you probably want to use [Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24395639/608639) or [Domain Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24030591/608639). They are some of the fastest IPC methods. Also see [Unix domain socket VS named pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9475442/608639).

Answer (score 2):

> Does it possible to communicate two process in different languages by using UDP

Yes. UDP is a well-defined protocol. Not a programming language or a platform.